# Ubuntu software centre not responding

Tags: software-center

Software centre is not responding. Whenever I open it the screen becomes black and I cannot do any thing. Instead I have to force quit the application, please provide me a solution.

Comment: Can you give us details? Is there an error displayed? Any console output? We may do magic here, but we need all the info we can get.

Comment: what was the output of `software-center` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a `sudo apt-get install software-center` from a terminal to upgrade your version of software-center. Possibly there is a new version already that fixes this error.

If that does not help, try running `sudo software-center` from a terminal and check the terminal output for any clues why it is not starting and possibly post the relevant output back here again.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and reinstall your software center with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

then try again.